# Vim doesn't display markdown the right way for specific file

Tags: vim, markdown

## Description

I have a file named `system-monitor.md` which doesn't display `markdown` rightly, then I `cat system-monitor.md > new.md`, everything in `new.md` displays the right way. How to fix it?
In `system-monitor.md`:
[image]

In `new.md`:
[image]

Comment: In what way does it "not display rightly"? What are its contents?

Comment: @Chris Image upload.

Comment: I would check the encoding and any BOM (if there is one). If there is a difference between `new.md` and `system-monitor.md`, then adjust accordingly.

Comment: @Waylan file-encoding and filetype are the same.And there is no BOM.

Comment: @Waylan I `Ctrl + f` to view the file, then all `markdown` displays the right way. It is so weird.